# VS2017: C# UWP "The method or operation is not implemented"

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, creators-update

I am using VS2017 and I am writing an UWP App at build level 16299 (Fall Creators' Update). After deploying and re-deploying a few times, I am unable to open any .CS file and if I force them to open (F7), I am getting this error.

[image: Error when trying to open any .CS file]

Funny thing is, the last deployed version of the app is working fine with no error and I can keep building and deploying it. I just cannot view/edit any CS code any longer. XAML editor is working fine though. So I created another solution and imported the same project there and that worked fine for a while too and then the same behavior started to appear. This has happened thrice so far before I gave up.

I am quite baffled by this because I cannot determine what action of mine is causing this. Furthermore, if I go to the project properties, this error starts to appear in most of the tabs.

[image: Project Properties]

Any advice in helping me restoring the project consistency and the peace of my mind will be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a sample  that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure how to reproduce this issue. It will work if I create a new solution and import the project again (ofcourse I have to re-install the nuget packages). At some point of time, any .cs file that was open, will close and you won't be able to open them anymore. I reinstalled Visual Studio once more and still had the problem. And once it starts happening, it happens for any existing solution/project that I try to run.